# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x48 in tid 21741 (RenderThread) in android in rear case in some device

Tags: android, android-activity, crash-reports, crashlytics

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x48 in tid 21741 (RenderThread) in occured in the rearest case in some device.If anyone knows please answer.Due to this error android application crash at every activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"/>
```

[crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inZwr.jpg)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved.

just add: `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in manifest file in activity

```
<activity
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:name=".HomeActivity"/>
```

Reference:
[Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).

Comment: You can accept the answer by ticking below the reputation at the left of your answer.

Comment: Your answer worked for me, I'm just curious to know why ?

Comment: @ArteFact

Please check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel